# How to run python code on AWS (EC2/Lambda)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

This post is to get basic information/links to understand running Py code on either Lambda or EC2.

My code structure is pretty simple:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#load more packages

input_data = pd.read_csv(...)

def do_stuff(input, parameters):
     action1
     action2
     output.to_csv(...)
     plt.save_fig(...)

do_stuff(input_data,input_parameter)
```

I need to run this code on AWS, but I am not sure which to use: Lambda or EC2.
Also, the input file is on my local PC, and output gets saved to a specific folder. Do I need to save it to the S3. If so, how does the path look like? Do I still use `import os`

I'm sorry for this noob like question. I need some starting guidance on what should I read to get started. Going through the AWS documentation becomes technical - and from the "Hello World" on Lambda - I couldn't understand much. Due to the lockdown, I'm unable to use my office desktop, and my personal mac cannot handle the loads. The input and output files are pretty small - cumulatively less than 5 MB (there are multiple input files).

Comment: A couple of relevant questions: Where do the input files come from ? How often do you have to run this function?

Comment: These input files are from a dataset that I've cleaned. I essentially am looking at AWS to run my code rather than running them on my personal PC. There is no schedule for running the files - I need to run it to create outputs which I further analyse through basic stats stuff.

Comment: How often does this need to run?  What would trigger it to run?

Comment: I run it whenever I need output data with revised parameters. Its not triggered by any live event per see - as and when I make progress with my research work to identify new parameter values.

Answer (score 2):

If this is something that needs to be done often, you could potentially create a workflow where you:

1. Upload the input *.csv* file into a **S3** bucket
2. Your **AWS Lambda** function listens for changes in the S3 bucket and your code is
   triggered to run when a new file is uploaded.
3. Your code saves the output *.csv* to a second **S3** bucket.

The code might look very roughly like this (modified from [this example )](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html):

```
import boto3
import os
import sys
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
def handle_csv(original_csv_path, output_csv_path):
    <process csv code>

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
        tmpkey = key.replace('/', '')
        download_path = <insert path here>
        upload_path = <insert path here>
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        handle_csv(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '<>'.format(bucket), key)
```

A path might look like:  `'<bucket/object>': 'input_csvs/1.csv'`

Comment: How does the path look like? For example, when running locally its "\users\....\data.csv". But how does it work with files in S3. Also, can I simply import packages such as scipy and pandas with the import command itself in Lamdba?

Comment: Unfortunately, Lambda does not support scipy or pandas out of the box. There are added steps needed for setting that environment up. For example: https://hackersandslackers.com/pandas-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 2):

This the OP here, and though I don't have a good answer here - I can summarize what I've figured out.

Lambda:
I found a helpful [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8L4OxotXlE) to understand how to get Lambda working. Also, to use Py packages such as numpy and pandas, you'll need to add a Lambda layer. I was able to do it by going through this [Medium post](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-amazon-lambda-layers-and-boto3-using-python3-39bd390add17). But I hadn't completely figured out how to connect my input CVS files and export my output CSV file. I stopped dead in my tracks when I realized Lambda can run for a max continuous runtime of 15mins. My Markov simulation code takes 24 hours - so Lambda was out of question, and I didn't pursue further. (P.S: I read later there are some "complicated" ways to make it work - but nah - I wasn't even clear how will Lambda services get charged).

EC2: There are couple of resources that helped a lot for running my code on a EC2 AWS Linux server. A [medium post on running Jupyter server](https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6) was the most helpful, and then I switched to using python and conda on the terminal itself through a[nother helpful medium post](https://medium.com/@andras1000_18467/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-cloud-e486eef96ac3). Further, I'm using the dropbox API and python package to push my output files to the cloud from the code run on EC2.

TLDR: Lambda won't work for me, and EC2 worked largely thanks to a [medium post](https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6). Also, I need to understand how CLI code works to get a better grasp of how things work.