# What AWS services allow for sharing/hosting of Python pandas code?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, anaconda

I have some Python Pandas code (this isn't really relevant to the question at hand, so, I am not including it). I have several functions that call one another and perform some statistical operations on data stored in excel/csv files.

My code is a jupyter notebook file in an Anaconda environment that has several libraries installed (Pandas, numpy, openpyxl,...). Now that the code is done, I would like to make this available to other users. I read up that AWS can be used as a service for hosting (and compiling) code on. I looked at this post [How to run python code on AWS (EC2/Lambda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62489657/how-to-run-python-code-on-aws-ec2-lambda) to get a better idea on AWS EC2 and AWS Lambda. Both seem fine, though, I was wondering if there are any other AWS services that could host python code. Here are some specifications that need to be fulfilled:

1. The code **must** be shareable (i.e., I can give a user access to the code, and they can run it, even if they are not knowledgeable about programming). That's essentially the end goal--that anyone can run/use it.
2. It is not an event driven code (so, I guess AWS Lambda is off). Essentially, a user uploads a data file from their pc to the code hosted on AWS. This triggers the code to run and it outputs a csv file with the statistical details to the user's desktop.
3. The aim is that users can run this during the night, so, the runtime of the code will be at least 9+ hours.
4. Since I have the code in an Anaconda environment, I will have to convert the environment (with the libraries) to a zip file and then upload it. Does any AWS service allow for using additional python libraries/dependencies.

Sorry if these questions seem kind of general. I have never used AWS before and want to make sure that it can actually accomplish what I want before I ask my organization for access to AWS.